# My JS function won't "alert" the keypress

Tags: javascript

I have this code and it doesn't seem to alert the fact that I'm pressing a key (this should happen after I click Start). Why wouldn't it? :/

```
function dynamic_buttons() {
    var start_button = document.getElementById('start');
    var stop_button = document.getElementById('stop');
    start_button.onclick = log_keypress;
    stop_button.onclick = log_keypress;
    }

function log_keypress() {
    alert('click event happened'); 
    }
```

Here's the "whole" fiddle: [code](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dQR6j/)

Comment: You are not calling the function, ever!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to call the `dynamic_buttons` function to bind the events.

updated fiddle

http://fiddle.jshell.net/dQR6j/5/

```
function dynamic_buttons() {
var start_button = document.getElementById('start');
var stop_button = document.getElementById('stop');
start_button.onclick = log_keypress;
stop_button.onclick = log_keypress;
}

function log_keypress() {
  alert('click event happened'); 
}

dynamic_buttons(); // <--- this is important
```

Answer (score 1):

You were not calling the `dynamic_buttons()` function, so your event handlers were never attached:

```
function dynamic_buttons() {
    var start_button = document.getElementById('start');
    var stop_button = document.getElementById('stop');
    start_button.onclick = log_keypress;
    stop_button.onclick = log_keypress;
    }


function log_keypress() {
    alert('click event happened'); 
    }

dynamic_buttons();
```

By the way, you are talking about `keypress`, but in your code, you are attaching handlers to the `click` event.

Comment: yeah, it gets a bit complicated. I changed it, though, to "start_button.onkeypress"  and now it's better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not called the function `dynamic_buttons`
http://fiddle.jshell.net/dQR6j/4/

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling "dynamic_buttons()" function. Try this:

```
function dynamic_buttons() {
    var start_button = document.getElementById('start');
    var stop_button = document.getElementById('stop');
    start_button.onclick = log_keypress;
    stop_button.onclick = log_keypress;
};

dynamic_buttons();

function log_keypress() {
    alert('click event happened'); 
}
```